# How do I limit Entry in a range of cells to be numeric (whole #) max length 9 chracters, no leading zeros and no duplicates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How do I limit Entry in a range of cells to be numeric (whole #) max length 9 chracters, no leading zeros and no duplicates?

I also want to limit another range of cells to maximum 24 alpha and "-" only

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your question can be accomplished with data validation and a custom format.  To do this, first select the entire range to be validated, and then click the Data Validation button in the Data ribbon.  Then to set the custom format, within the Settings tab of the Data Validation dialog, change the Allow dropdown to "Custom" and paste or type the formula including the leading `=` into the Formula box:

```
=AND(A1 > 0, A1 < 1000000000, A1 = INT(A1), COUNTIF(A:A, A1) <= 1)
```

- The `AND` formula returns true if all of its arguments are true.
- `A1 > 0` validates that the number is positive.
- `A1 < 1000000000` validates that the number is at most 9 characters long.
- `A1 = INT(A1)` validates that the number is not a decimal.
- `COUNTIF(A:A, A1) <= 1` validates that the range contains only 1 instance of the number.

There is no need to check that there are no leading zeroes unless the range is formatted as text since Excel automatically removes any leading zeroes from numbers.

This formula assumes your target range is column A.  Change all instances of `A1` in the formula to the first cell in the target range and the `$A:$A` to the entire range.  Be sure to use the relative reference form when referring to the first cell and the absolute reference form when referring to the entire range (i.e. `B1` for the first cell and `$B$1:$B$20` for the entire range.)

The benefits of using data validation are that there is no need to use macros and you can specify a custom input message and custom error message right within the Data Validation dialog.

The second part of your question cannot be easily accomplished without some VBA.  If you are working with a table and applying the data validation to a column, this can easily be accomplished by using a hidden column and a custom function similar to the following:

```
Function LimitAlpha24(str As String) As Boolean
    Dim rx As Object
    Set rx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    rx.Pattern = "^[A-Za-z-]{0,24}$"
    LimitAlpha24 = rx.Test(str)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, v As Variant, L As Long, i As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set A = Range("A1:A10")
    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    v = Target.Text
    L = Len(v)

    If L > 9 Then
        MsgBox "input too long"
        GoTo errOut
    End If

    For i = 1 To L
        If Mid(v, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
        Else
            MsgBox "bad character"
            GoTo errOut
        End If
    Next i

    If Left(v, 1) = "0" Then
        MsgBox "leading zero"
        GoTo errOut
    End If

    If wf.CountIf(A, v) > 1 Then
        MsgBox "duplicate value"
        GoTo errOut
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

errOut:
    Target.Clear
    Target.Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The assumed range of cells is **A1:A10**

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**